# Capturar conteúdo variável imagem

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho uma aplicação HTML5 que captura uma imagem da webcam pelo browser a qual preciso capturar e gravar no banco de dados como um binário.

Do lado servidor, em PHP, eu tenho:

```
$directory = $img;
$element_img = base64_encode(file_get_contents($directory));
```

E o processo de captura no cliente, com Javascript, se dá através do evento onClick de um botão, que após capturado envia ela para outra janela que eu abro no browser:

```
function btnCaptura() {
    var img = App.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    window.open(img, "_blank", "menubar=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,width=" + App.canvas.width + ",height=" + App.canvas.height);

}
```

E apesar de funcionar, isto é, a imagem capturada ser enviada para janela aberta, preciso enviar essa imagem para o PHP para que ela possa ser gravada no banco, mas não estou conseguindo.

Obs: Caso seja possível fazer tudo na mesma janela, sem abrir uma nova, apenas mostrando um aviso de que a imagem foi capturada com sucesso, seria melhor.

Comment: Testa o que te falei na resposta e retorna caso tenha algum problema.

Comment: Posso colocar o código da sua função salvar dentro da minha função btnCaptura ficando assim: function btnCaptura() {
    var img = App.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(img, "_self", "menubar=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,width=" + App.canvas.width + ",height=" + App.canvas.height);
 sessionStorage.setItem('imagem', img); /* se for conveniente manter os dados depois de o usuário fechar o navegador, crie uma localStorage no lugar de uma sessionStorage */
   alert("Salvo com sucesso");
   location.reload();
}

Comment: Pra quê você vai usar o open() ? Não há necessidade, nesse seu caso.

Comment: Olha lá na minha resposta como é.

Comment: comentei a linha //window.open(img...... conforme seu exemplo capturei o conteúdo da variável img que está no javascript, no php ficou assim: $img = "<script> sessionStorage.getItem('imagem');</script>"; 
   var_dump ($img);
   $directory = $img;
   $element = base64_encode(file_get_contents($directory));
   echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$element.' "/>'; esstá dando erro->>>>>string(51) "" Warning: file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: Pra você passar url como nome de arquivo você deve ter allow_url_fopen no php.ini ativado. Vê se é isso.

Comment: Directive; Local Value; Master Value;
allow_url_fopen; On;         On;

Answer (score 1):

Bem, quanto a abrir na mesma janela, basta substituir o `_blank` por `_self`, nota; se você deixar o parâmetro em branco, o padrão é `_blank`.
Quanto a salvar o conteúdo em uma variável php, você pode salvar a imagem em uma sessionStorage, depois recarregar a página.

```
function btnCaptura() {
   var img = App.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   sessionStorage.setItem('imagem', img); /* se for conveniente manter os dados depois de o usuário fechar o navegador, crie uma localStorage no lugar de uma sessionStorage. */
   alert("Salvo com sucesso");
   location.reload();
}
```

Logo, no seu php basta colocar:

```
$img = "<script> sessionStorage.getItem('imagem');</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer usando jquery com ajax assim:

```
var img = App.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
$.ajax({
    type: POST, url: 'urlpagina.php'
        data: { 
            imagem   : img,
        }
    }).done(function( res ) {
        // res conterá a resposta de urlpagina.php, faça o que quiser com ele
    });
```

vc ainda pode enviar por ajax sem usar o Jquery. Mas usando ele é bem mais fácil. Se quiser fazer sem o Jquery tem um exemplo aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

O PHP vai receber a imagem na variável de sistema $_POST['imagem'] como é comum em submits.

Comment: Caro Nelson. Ao tentar utilizar o seu código dentro da function btnCaptura ficando assim: function btnCaptura() {
    var img = App.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 $.ajax({
  type: POST, url: 'urlpagina.php'
   data: { 
    imagem   : img,
   }
 }).done(function( res ) {
        // res conterá a resposta de urlpagina.php, faça o que quiser com ele
 });
 
} //Com isso ao carregar no browser ele não deixa aparecer a janela de permissão de acesso a webcam do usuário exemplo ->>>>>>>http://webcamtoy.com/pt/

Comment: o código acima é só pra ilustrar uma chamada Ajax. Se precisa de passar por essa janela de permissão, coloque em uma função separa o código onde ela aparece e sincronamente obtenha o valor que precisa. Depois faça a chamada Ajax. Se não souber o que é síncrono e assíncrono diga que eu explico.